# Discord bot code that reacts to a specific message using message_id

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

This is the snipet of a code I have written for my discord bot, where it *should* be able to react to a specific message with the custom emoji `\<:sallynice:1085290242304651364\>` using `message_id` to fetch it. Problem is it doesn't work. No errors are shown when I run the code, but nothing happens when I try to use it on my server. The bot has all the permissions it needs too. Help?

```py
@client.command()
async def reactnice(ctx, message_id: int):
\# Retrieve the message using its ID
message = await ctx.fetch_message(message_id)
\# Add the desired reaction to the message
await message.add_reaction('\<:sallynice:1085290242304651364\>')
```

Tried to see if the bot can delete a message but that also doesn't do anything either.

```py
@client.command()
async def delete_message(ctx, message_id: int):
\# Retrieve the message using its ID
message = await ctx.fetch_message(message_id)
\# Delete the message
await message.delete()
```

This also didnt work

```py
@client.command()
async def reactnice(ctx, message: discord.Message):
\# Add the desired reaction to the message
await message.add_reaction('\<:sallynice:1085290242304651364\>')
```

Comment: Also these look correct to add a reaction, but we don't have any information about what triggers the functions. It's likely that they are never running, you can set up logging to see what's happening https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html

Comment: As @VioletRosenzweig, try to include a traceback if there is one. If there isn't, then tell us if adding a print statement within the command does anything. Also some of the code snippets are not indented properly. That may be causing the issue.